# How is LDAP supposed to be used with sarg (Squid Analysis Report Generator)?

Tags: ldap, squid

The sarg.conf documentation implies that LDAP can be used to lookup a username from an ip address or hostname by setting the line 'usertab ldap'. But it is my understanding that LDAP can't be used for this kind of lookup. Instead the Windows security event logs should be parsed instead.

If this is the case, then what is LDAP supposed to be used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you carefully read the docs, you will notice that it only talks about *user names* in connection with LDAP directories. When IP->user mapping is mentioned, the document always talks about tables, meaning the other possible data source for the `usertab` parameter, text tables containing that mapping information.

So, `sarg`  appears to use LDAP directories only to map user names to real names (e.g. jdoe =>  Jane Doe), not for IP mappings. This is a fairly standard use case for LDAP in many applications.

In theory, it would be possible to contain a list with IP->user mappings in an LDAP directory, but I've never seen this.